# How to install something on Linux without Makefile (lessc in this case)

Tags: linux, makefile, installation, less

I am relatively new to the Linux world so forgive this question if it is simple. I have cloned the lessc repo from this url: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js

However I cannot find a way of installing it. Am I missing something or is there a manual way to install things setup like this. I have encountered this problem several times and would appreciate any input you could offer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - I'm not familiar with this particular package ... but if it wants you to do a "make install", what's wrong with doing a "make install"?  Just asking...

Comment: It does not want that. It doesn't work.

Comment: You probably want to install on you Linux distribution the necessary packages to build software. On Debian or Ubuntu, install the `build-essential` package

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install lessc with make install.

It is not a binary program, it's a javascript, so you jut have to copy in the correct position of your website.

Unlike programs, which have a specified position where they have to be installed, files that have to be served by webserver do not have an install script, because there's not fixed position in the filesystem where a website is stored.

Comment: No. less.js is not a binary but lessc is a compiler you can install and run on a server. It's much better than using the javascript because that compiles for each user whereas lessc compiles .less files into .css files when you run it. That way the website never sees the .less files.